# how do i make a correct if statement based of an input

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

new to coding

was trying to make a number generator game where you guess a number and it says if it is higher or lower

however i am having issues with the code: an if statement which depends on the input and says if the number is higher or lower. Any answers would be greatly appreciated.

```py
if input > x:
   print('smaller')
   if input == x:
        print('correct')
```

Comment: `input() != input`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

`input()` returns a string, so you have to convert it to an integer.

```
guess = int(input('Enter your guess: '))
if guess < x:
    print('your guess is smaller')
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome, Amar.
Building on John's response.

```
# declare the number say 80

x = 80
guess = int(input('Enter your guess: '))

if guess < x:
    print('your guess is smaller')
elif guess > x:
    print('your guess is greater')
else:
    print('You have guessed the correct number')
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Make the input type to a integer

```
Guess = int(input('enter your number's))
```